# Symmetry Group for 6-digit Binary Number

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let us say that two 6-digit binary numbers are equivalent if one can be obtained by the other by any number of FLIP and SHIFT operations. Recall that FLIP(000000) = 111111 and SHIFT(101000) = 010001.

We know that for 5-digit binary numbers, the set of operations $H := \{I, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, F\}$ (where $S_i$ denotes a left shift by $i$ places, and $F$ denotes the FLIP operation) is not sufficient to form a group, and we must add the operations $FS_1, FS_2, FS_3, FS_4$ (which denotes the composition of $F$ and $S_i$). Therefore, the symmetry group for 5-digit binary numbers is in fact

$$G := \{I, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, F, FS_1, FS_2, FS_3, FS_4\}.$$

However, for 6-digit binary numbers, the following set of operations (using the same notation as before)

$$H := \{I, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5, F, FS_1, FS_2, FS_3, FS_4, FS_5\}$$

does not result in a group because the operations result in redundant permutations. I'm not sure how to remedy the situation although I know that it has to do with the fact that there are an even number of digits in a 6-digit binary number. Have I included more operations in the set $H$ than necessary? And why?

Comment: Should $\text{SHIFT}(101000)=010100$? Otherwise could you explain what you mean?

Comment: We are talking essentially about the same thing. Except you used a right shift and I used a left shift.

Comment: Does the "FLIP" operation negate each bit in-place?

Comment: Yes, yes, it does.

Comment: In which sense do you say that $H$ is not a group? It has a binary composition, is associative, has a neutral element and inverses of every element -- which is all that is necessary to be a goup. (It is isomorphic to the group $C_6\times C_2$, in fact). It even operates faithfully on $\{0,1\}^6$ since, for example, the image of `000001` is different under each of the elements of $H$.

Comment: The question is: is there too many elements necessary in $H$ to make it a group? Can we trim the group down? And where?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "too many elements to make it a group". It is a perfectly fine group as far as I can see.